# How to send my data in headers in post request .?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I want to send my data in headers, so I converted my data into base64 and I'm getting the output in `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']`. But how to post the basic auth data in headers in the post request

```
.factory('Auth', function (Base64,$http, AuthToken) { //for login/logout
    var authFactory = {};
    authFactory.login = function (loginData) {
        var authdata = Base64.encode(loginData.username + ':' + loginData.password);
        var userData = {
                username: loginData.username ,
                authdata: authdata
        }
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata;
        return $http.post('http://cc92e1dd.ngrok.io/api/authenticate',{'Authorization':'Basic ' + authdata})//is this correct format to send? 
        .then(function (data) {
            AuthToken.setToken(data.data.token);
            return data;
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below, just put you params into headers:

```
$http.get(url, 
    { headers: { 
        'Cache-Control' : 'public', 
        'Pragma': '', 
        'Accept-Encoding':
        'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authdata
       }
    });
```